# Why can I not post to my mysql DB with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Good day everyone

I've searched and searched and cannot seem to figure out what, exactly, is wrong with my script.  I'm, simply, trying to insert a row into a MySQL DB via PHP it shows all for Steps but doesn't update the record in the table.  My Script is

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('callingonchristcom.ipagemysql.com', 'jhedge', 'mypw'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db('user'); 
echo 'Step Two';
$mysqlstr="INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw');";
echo 'Step Three';
mysql_query($myquerystr);
echo 'Step Four';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: You are using **INSERT** query and saying **but doesn't update the record** ?

Comment: Correct.  When I check the Users table on the User DB it has no records.

Comment: you dont check fir any errors, so you will never know

Comment: Could it be that your MySQL server has `autocommit` set to `off`?

Comment: can you show us your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query variable is `$mysqlstr` and you are using `$myquerystr` in your mysql_query So that will not insert

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Note : Please use mysqli instead of mysql.**

please remove extra semicolumn (;) from your query.

Replace

```
$mysqlstr="INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw');";
```

with

```
$mysqlstr="INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')";
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried that but it still is not updating.

Answer (score 0):

echo $mysqlstr;
This will give the exact string which is passed to mysql_query .. output this onto the console and execute this string directly in php admin to see if any errors pop up.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  I tried it in the console and it added the record fine in the console.

Comment: INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')

Comment: echo mysql_error(); add this after mysql_query() to see if any errors are printed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using below code.  I have updated your code

```
<?php 
$link = mysql_connect('callingonchristcom.ipagemysql.com', 'jhedge', 'mypw'); 
if (!$link) { 
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysql_select_db('user',$link); 
echo 'Step Two';
$mysqlstr="INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES  ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')";
echo 'Step Three';
mysql_query($mysqlstr,$link);
echo 'Step Four';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

You missed passing  database connection object in select db and query function.

Comment: Thank you.  I tried but it still didn't update the DB with any records.

Comment: Try to print  `$link` connection object. Seems your connection is not eastablished. Also I would like to know the connection driver placed in your folder or not

Comment: Thank you again.  It prints as Resource id #2 (whatever that means).  My web hosting is done through ipage.com so I am uncertain where the driver(s) are placed.  How can I find that out?

Comment: I think i found out the error you have passing wrong variabale name in mysql_query($mysqlstr,$link);

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try link this....Use mysqli instead of mysql.

```
<?php 
$link = mysqli_connect('callingonchristcom.ipagemysql.com', 'jhedge', 'mypw'); 
if (!$link) { 
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error()); 
} 
echo 'Connected successfully'; 
mysqli_select_db('user'); 
echo 'Step Two';
$mysqlstr = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')";
echo 'Step Three';
mysqli_query($link,$myquerystr);
echo 'Step Four';
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks again - however this didn't update the DB either

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be your variables, unless you had a typo when posting. You initially use `$mysqlstr`but then you use `$myquerystr`. Regardless, you would benefit much greatly by using the Mysqli object oriented structure. Redo your code in this manner and let me know what you get:

```
$servername = "callingonchristcom.ipagemysql.com";
$username = "jhedge";
$password = "mypw";
$dbname = "user";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: That's it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all don't use `mysql` driver for database operations it s depreciated

Use `pdo` or `mysqli` driver

here is a minimal  example with  `mysqli` driver

```
    $db_name="students";
    $db_username="root";
    $db_password="pass";

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost",$db_username,$db_password,$db_name);
    $query="INSERT INTO users (FirstName,LastName,UserName,Password) VALUES ('John','Hedge','jhedge','mypw')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);

    if($result->num_rows==1){
       echo 'Insert success';
     }else {
      echo 'Error insert';
   }
```